# Call a function from another contract (by caller contract)

Tags: solidity

I need to call a function from another contract, but is it possible that the caller is the calling contract, and not msg.sender/wallet?

For example

```
contract BrainGame {

    function updateGameScores(uint _scores, address _user) public onlyAdmin {
        userScores[_user] = _scores;
    }

}
```

The `onlyAdmin` modifier is defined in the contract, and the `UserPlay` contract is added as an Admin (which could update the scores)

```
contract UserPlay {
    BrainGame bg = BrainGame(0x000ContractAddress000);

    function playGame(uint _fun) public {
        /// game logic goes
        
        bg.updateGameScores(_fun, msg.sender);
    }

}
```

My question is, can `updateGameScores` function be called by `UserPlay` instead of wallet/msg.sender?
Can we call a function (from another contract) and caller be the calling contract (instead of wallet/msg.sender)?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you define in onlyAdmin modifier?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and in this case it will be. Msg.sender is the last contract/entity in the contract call stack, and tx.origin is what you use to get the original wallet of whoever started the interaction in the first place. Usually you do not want to use tx.origin in practice.